# Does Lebesgue measure zero imply measure zero with respect to any measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Must $A$ have measure zero with respect to every measure $\mu$ for which $A$ is $\mu$-measurable? If not, then is there a simple condition on $\mu$ to ensure this?

Comment: Consider the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure)

Comment: No, as long as $A$ is non-empty, there is some measure for which $A$ is not zero.

Comment: Following up the previous two comments, for any measurable space $(X,\mathfrak{M})$, and any $A\in\mathfrak{M}$, suppose it satisfies the following condition: for any measure $\mu$ defined on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mu(A)=0$. Then, one can conclude $A=\emptyset$. For the proof, simply take $\mu$ to be the counting measure.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a nice class of measures for which this property does hold? I am particularly interested in Haar measures with respect to an arbitrary locally compact Lie group.

Comment: Your second question is interesting. Reformulating, is there a way to determine the measures $\mu$ such that the set of Lebesgue-null sets is contained in the $\mu$-null sets? Of course, any constant times the Lebesgue measure satisfies this, so you have infinitely many. In particular you have the zero measure. 
Any such $\mu$ must have a looser definition of almost everywhere, thus the related integral is "coarser", in a way.

Comment: @Ben : for Matrix Lie groups the [Haar measure](http://pcteserver.mi.infn.it/~molinari/NOTES/haar.pdf) is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: For Polish spaces there is a notion of universally measure zero sets, that is sets $X$ such that $\mu(X)=0$ for every nonatomic Borel measure

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Ben : The link I posted, or, if you want, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Examples) without much reference. I have calculated Haar myself for $SU(2)$. Therefore I trust this. See also [this](http://mf23.web.rice.edu/LA_2_v1.4%20Lie%20groups%20as%20manifolds;%20su(2)%20and%20S3.pdf)